# Error in parsing form-data in Node Express

Tags: json, express, multer, form-data, body-parser

I have an express service which has an endpoint that consumes a POST call with form-data in XML.

[Postman Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5YQX.png)

I'm using `multer` and `express-xml-bodyparser` and my `index.js` looks like:

```html
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const xmlparser = require('express-xml-bodyparser');
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer()
const redact = { redact: ['body.*', 'value.body'] };
const modsRoute = require('./routes/mods');


process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0;

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(xmlparser());
app.use(upload.none());

app.post('/request', modsRoute.postMethod)


module.exports = app;
```

The problem is that when I try to print the content of the request body in my router method:

```html
const postMethod = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    console.log('body: ', req.body);
    res.status(200).send();
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

I get a weird object:

```html
body:  [Object: null prototype] {
  'api-key': '1a393779-c191-11e3-ae50-80c16e6a4098',
  data: '<subscriber>\n' +
    '\t<action>add</action>\n' +
    '\t<customer_id>529</customer_id>\n' +
    '\t<subscriber_details>\n' +
    '    <unique_id>123UniqueID</unique_id>\n' +
    '\t\t<firstname>First</firstname>\n' +
    '\t\t<lastname>Test</lastname>\n' +
    '\t\t<address1>999 Street</address1>\n' +
    '\t\t<address2></address2>\n' +
    '\t\t<city>Scottsdale</city>\n' +
    '\t\t<state>AZ</state>\n' +
    '\t\t<zip>85253</zip>\n' +
    '    <email>email@infoarmor.com</email>\n' +
    '    <dob_month>00</dob_month>\n' +
    '\t\t<dob_day>00</dob_day>\n' +
    '\t\t<dob_year>0000</dob_year>\n' +
    '\t\t<phone>9999999999</phone>\n' +
    '\t\t<options>\n' +
    '\t\t\t<plan_type>1</plan_type>\n' +
    '      <ew_status>0</ew_status>\n' +
    '\t\t</options>\n' +
    '\t\t<billing_information>\n' +
    '\t\t\t<bill_type>prd</bill_type>\n' +
    '\t\t</billing_information>\n' +
    '\t</subscriber_details>\n' +
    '</subscriber>'
}
```

As it can be seen, the object contains all the newline and whitespace characters and it hasn't really converted it into JSON.

I also tried to convert the whole body into JSON with `JSON.parse()` but I got an exception thrown. I also tried to first `stringify()` the body and then parse it.
In that case, I could only get the `data` field but I was again an expection when trying to get the `api-key` field.

Do I need to add any other middleware in order to get at least a correct JSON object of `req.body` even though the field `data` is still in XML and not JSON?

Comment: `req.body` is, as expected, an `Object`. If you want to access the fields, use `req.body['api-key']` (bracket notation because of the hyphen in the property name) and `req.body.data`. I don't know why you think it should be JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can send json data to user using like this

```
const postMethod = async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
        
        res.json({"Hello":"World"});
       //  you can send anything json back including req.body like 
       // this res.json(req.body);

        } catch (err) {
        next(err);
        }
    };
```